# Tool for PDF conversion to black and white

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Is there a freely available (preferably open source) tool or library for PDF conversion to black and white?

Some customers want to print generated PDF documents in B&W to save toner. Unfortunately I cannot generate PDF in B&W directly, since we are merging two PDF pages together, one being official not available in B&W.

**Update:** To be more specific, I am looking for automatic solution, i.e. tool that is callable from a program.

Comment: Do you really mean 'black and white'? Or do you mean 'grayscale'?

Comment: @pipitas Yes, black and white

Comment: You don't seem to know that each printer using only black toner can print many levels of grayscale. So a grayscale PDF (like created by command from 'Ghostscript' answer) is certainly good to go for your customer...

Comment: @Villiam: "Pathetic" is in the eyes of the observer only. Congratulations! You're one of those who can "see". -- I **know** how to solve such problems reported by customers, and I get paid for this. Your original problem description didn't mention the dark red background. To find a really well working solution for such a problem one needs to see a sample PDF exhibiting it. Because converting to "black-and-white-without-any-grayscale" could well result turning your "dark red" into black and then you're still screwed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PrimoPDF (http://www.primopdf.com/index.aspx) you should be able to set to generate a "Black & White" pdf.

"Printing Preferences" -> "Paper/Quality" tab, then you can choose between "Black & White" and "Color.

Regards
Thomas

Comment: Looks good, thanks. But I was hoping to get something I can call automatically from the application. I've updated the question now.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I selected "Black and White" print paper but the resulting PDF still contained color.

Answer (score 23):

Having seen Viliam's insisting on wanting *"Black and White"*, not *"Grayscale"* I'm **still** offering this solution to convert PDF files to grayscale. Because I think that would perfectly fullfil the requirement to *"save color toner"* and make use of black toner only.

**Use Ghostscript** (the most recently released version is 9.05) with this command:

```
 gs \
   -o black+white.pdf \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
   -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
   -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=Gray \
   -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray \
   -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
    /path/to/input.pdf
```

On Windows, use `gswin32c.exe` or `gswin64c.exe` instead of `gs`. Ghostscript meets Viliam's request for:

- freely available
- Open Source
- callable from a program

and it does the job.

---

#### Update

If color conversion does not work as desired and if you see a message like *"Unable to convert color space to Gray, reverting strategy to LeaveColorUnchanged"* then...

1. your Ghostscript probably is a newer release from the *9.x version series*, and
2. your source PDF likely uses an embedded *ICC color profile*

In this case add **`-dOverrideICC`** to the command line and see if it changes the result as desired.

Comment: Also was helpful to me. Here is the command line I used in windows:
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.05\bin\gswin64.exe" -o top_black.pdf    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -sColorConversionStrategyForImages=Gray  -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 c:\path\to\inputFile.pdf

Comment: I tried this with gs 9.10 on Ubuntu, got "Unable to convert color space to Gray, reverting strategy to LeaveColorUnchanged.", discovered answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20133915/223837, and that solved this message.  I don't know which of the different flags actually makes a difference.

Comment: Recent Ghostscript versions have extended their support to handle ICC profiles. So if your PDF had an ICC color profile embedded this might have prevent Ghostscript from following your conversion orders. In these cases, adding a **`-dOverrideICC`** parameter would enforce your desired color conversion.

Comment: Devs say ([1](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=700819#c1),[2](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693716#c4),[3](https://ghostscript.com/irclogs/2012/11/21.html),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36337225/1032586)) that there's no `-sColorConversionStrategyForImages` switch.

Answer (score 3):

Try this website,

http://online.puzzleflow.com/process/all2gray

It worked for me.

**Update**

It has been made a payed website