# Converting PDF to GRAYSCALE using PDFBox without images?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

im using Apache PDFBox,

I want to convert a RGB PDF file to another GRAYSCALE file WITHOUT using images method because its making huge file size -_- !!

so this my steps:

1. Export a (A4) First.pdf from Adobe InDesign, contain images, texts, vector-objects.
2. I read the First.pdf file. Done!
3. using LayerUtility, copy pages from First.pdf rotate them and put them to NEW PDF file (A4) Second.pdf. Done!

   - this method preferred because i need vector-objects to reduce the size.
4. then, i want to save this as GRAY-SCALE PDF file (Second-grayscale.pdf)

and this my code (not all):

```
PDDocument documentFirst = PDDocument.load("First.pdf"));

// Second.pdf its empty always
PDDocument documentSecond = PDDocument.load("Second.pdf"));

for (int page = 0; page < documentSecond.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
    // get current page from documentSecond
    PDPage tempPage = documentSecond.getPage(page);

    // create content contentStream
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(documentSecond, tempPage);

    // create layerUtility
    LayerUtility layerUtility = new LayerUtility(documentSecond);

    // importPageAsForm from documentFirst
    PDFormXObject form = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(documentFirst, page);

    // saveGraphicsState
    contentStream.saveGraphicsState();

    // rotate the page
    Matrix matrix;
    matrix.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
    contentStream.transform(matrix);

    // draw the rotated page from documentFirst to documentSecond
    contentStream.drawForm(form);

    contentStream.close();
}

// save the new document
documentSecond.save("Second.pdf");

documentSecond.close();
documentFirst.close();

// now convert it to GRAYSCALE or do it in the Loop above!
```

> well, i just start using Apache Box this week, i have followed some
>   example, but most are old and not working, until now i did what i
>   need, just need the Grayscale :)!!

**if there are other solutions in java using open-source library
or a free tools. (i found with Ghost Script and Python)**

i read this example but i didn't understand it and there are a functions deprecated!:

https://github.com/lencinhaus/pervads/blob/master/libs/pdfbox/src/java/org/apache/pdfbox/ConvertColorspace.java

its about PDF Specs, and changing Color Space...

Comment: The example works for simple documents only. But a complete solution is highly non-trivial.

Comment: can PDFBox do the GrayScale Conversion?

Comment: Not "out of the box".

Comment: As far as I know there is no ready-to-use full-fledged pdfbox conversion routine, the example you reference covers only very simple cases. On the other hand pdfbox offers a framework for arbitrary pdf manipulations; thus, you can implement your own conversion based on pdfbox. So... *"can PDFBox do the GrayScale Conversion?"* - yes, but probably not out of the box. Add you don't share the pdf (or a representative example of the pdfs) in question, I cannot tell whether the example you found might already suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you would be interested in a Ghostscript based solution as far as I understood. 
If you are able to call GS from your command line you can do color to grayscale conversion with this command line

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dOverrideICC -o out.pdf -f input.pdf
```

my answer is taken from [How to convert a PDF to grayscale from command line avoiding to be rasterized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128656/how-to-convert-a-pdf-to-grayscale-from-command-line-avoiding-to-be-rasterized)